# C# Unity how could I make something every second?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Could someone tell how could I add to a variable every second 1?
Example:

[image]

Comment: [`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html), or [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) with [`while'(true){ yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); DoSomething(); }`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) or simply timer in [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) using e.g. [`timer += Time.deltaTime; if(timer >= 1){ timer = 0; DoSomething(); }`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) ... there are plenty of examples and options online ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try coroutines out:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class SecondCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(logEverySecond());
    }

    IEnumerator logEverySecond() {
        while (true) {
            Debug.Log("Tick");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }    
    }
}
```

Attach this script to gamobject in the scene and see in the console how the ticker logs.
Threre you could `SimpNum++`